# combine 2 if conditions without || and &&

Tags: php

hello i have 2 if conditions

```
$file ='ips.txt';

$ips = file($file);

$client = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$ips = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$linecount = 0;

$handle = fopen($file, "r");

while(!feof($handle)){
    $line = fgets($handle);
    $linecount++;
}

fclose($handle);

for($i=0;$i<$linecount;$i++){
    if (trim($ips[$i]) == $client){
        echo"dablokilia<br>"; 
        break;
    }
}

include "404.php";
```

and

```
       if(preg_match('/(Chrome|CriOS)\//i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
 && !preg_match('/(Aviator|ChromePlus|coc_|Dragon|Edge|Flock|Iron|Kinza|Maxthon|MxNitro|Nichrome|OPR|Perk|Rockmelt|Seznam|Sleipnir|Spark|UBrowser|Vivaldi|WebExplorer|YaBrowser)/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
   include '404.php';
}
```

How can i merge them to get 1 workable if condition?

So I want to get clients if then check it into my ips.txt file if it's on it don't load anything if it's not on it check if browser is chrome and then load 404.php

thanks

Comment: If the first condition is true, the second will always be false. You don't need both of them. Just check one or the other.

Comment: How can the broswer  ID itself as chrome and...not chrome? Chrome plus is not chrome

Comment: first detects ip and checks it on .txt file

Comment: second detects if browser is chrome

Comment: @Kisaragi Aviator has both `Chrome/` and `Aviator` in useragent string (and also [ChromePlus](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/ChromePlus/), actually)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
       if(preg_match('/(Chrome|CriOS)\//i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
 && !preg_match('/(Aviator|ChromePlus|coc_|Dragon|Edge|Flock|Iron|Kinza|Maxthon|MxNitro|Nichrome|OPR|Perk|Rockmelt|Seznam|Sleipnir|Spark|UBrowser|Vivaldi|WebExplorer|YaBrowser)/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
   echo (strpos(file_get_contents('ips.txt'), $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) !== false)?'':include 'page.php';
}


?>
```

i have fixed

that code checks if browser is chrome
if chrome it checks if ip is listed on  ips.txt if itsnot it loads code.php on index.html